# Translate in a specific language in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multilanguage website in Laravel 4.2, and would like to send an email notification to the admins in a specified language using the lang files.

How can I call `Lang::get('group.key')` specifying the needed language ?

Thank you for your help !

Edit: existing code: (the lang items are option1, option2, .., option6)

```
class EmailController extends BaseController {
    public static function contact(){
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required|digits_between:1,6',
            'message' => 'required'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if (!$validator->fails()){
            $data = ['subject' => Input::get('subject'), 
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'content' => Input::get('message')];
            Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message){
                $message->from(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'));
                $message->to('admin@email.com', 'Admin');
                $message->subject(Lang::get('contact.option'.Input::get('subject')));
            });
        }
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**There are 3 ways to achieve this:**

1. You can change default language at runtime by doing this:

`App::setLocale('fr');` 
NB: This is not suitable for your current need as it will only take effect on next page load.

2. You can set default language here **app/config/app.php**

`'fallback_locale' => 'fr'`

3. I took a deeper look at Illuminate\Translation\Translator:

   `get($key, array $replace = array(), $locale = null)`

   This means you can do this using Translator Facade:

   `Lang::get($key, array $replace = array(), $locale = null);`

   Example:

   `Lang::get('group.key',[],'fr');`

NB: You folder structure should look like this

```
/app
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
        /fr
            messages.php
```

Comment: Thank you, this is basic information on Localization in Laravel. However I was looking for a way to use a certain language without changing the user's locale. It turned out it doesn't.

Comment: @MPikkle Okay now i understand. Its very possible you need to simply supply the local as part of argument. I will now modify my answer.

Comment: This looks like a more comprehensive and (if option 3 works - cleaner) answer than the accepted one. Especially if it would mention that option 1 only persists the change until the next page load - i.e. it won't change what the user sees because of the redirect.

Comment: Thank you for your update, I did not know the existence of the two following parameters.

Comment: I think in Laravel 5 `App::setLocale('fr')` will take effect on runtime now.

Answer (score 22):

To get a language specific translation - different from the current locales without setting and unsetting the locales, just do

```
__('description_1', [], 'en')
```

Comment: I've found one caveat that if using the json translation files approach to translate into another language. For example, to have English default and French option, with this approach, there is no en.json, only fr.json, and the keys of the json are English, values French. I can't seem to use this solution to get the keys (English) while in the French locale by using this solution. I'm still working to find a way.

Comment: When using a single json file for another language with translation strings as keys, I've found I need to use `\Lang::get('*')` to load the json as an array in order to get the translation string keys. I needed this for a situation where I'm using json file with translation strings as keys but have an area of an app where I need to access those keys while in the other locale.

Comment: @Slivicon exactly same situation for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just set needed locale before calling `Lang::get()`:

```
App::setLocale('es');
```

Comment: Wouldn't that change the locale for the user ?

Comment: to answer this I need to see your code where you sending email

Comment: No, this wouldn't change the locale for the user as you redirect him right after sending email.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

return [
 'welcome' => 'welcome :name',
];

trans('welcome', [ 'name' => 'xyz' ], 'fr');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and found the desired answer.
This will provide you the desired result:

```
trans('welcome',array(),null,'fr');
```

This is working since `Laravel` vers. 5.2.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend something like this:

```
    $savedLocale = App::getLocale();
    App::setLocale($this->getUserMailingLanguage());
    Mail::to($this->e_mail)->send($mailable);
    App::setLocale($savedLocale);
```